# Returning jbyteArray from native c in Android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I use native c to read data from an audio file to jbyte pointer. Now i want to send it to java as an jbyteArray.

```
jbyteArray Java_com_app_audio_player_readData(JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj,jstring readPath)
{

FILE *fin;
const char *inFile= (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,readPath,0);
fin = fopen(inFile, "r");

fseek(fin, 0, SEEK_END); // seek to end of file
 int size = ftell(fin); // get current file pointer
fseek(fin, 0, SEEK_SET);

jbyte *data=(jbyte *)malloc(size*sizeof(jbyte));
int charCnt = 0;

charCnt=fread(data, 1, size, fin);


jbyteArray result=(*env)->NewByteArray(env, size);

     //-- I want to convert data to jbyteArray and return it to java    

fclose(fin);
 return result;

}
```

How it is done?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

use `SetByteArrayRegion`

```
charCnt=fread(data, 1, size, fin);

jbyteArray result=(*env)->NewByteArray(env, size);

(*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, result, 0, size, data);
```

one could also use `GetByteArrayElements`
eg:

```
jboolean isCopy;
jbyte* rawjBytes = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, result, &isCopy);

//do stuff to raw bytes
memcpy(rawjBytes, data, size*sizeof(jbyte));

(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, result, rawjBytes, 0);
```

[see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html) for more details on `SetByteArrayRegion`, `GetByteArrayElements` and `ReleaseByteArrayElements`.

**NB:** this question is probably a special case of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610045/how-to-return-an-array-from-jni-to-java)

Comment: @Roman ~but the intention here *is* to use `memcpy` to copy `data` into `rawjBytes`?! & demonstrates an alternative to `SetByteArrayRegion` where lets say, large `data` needs to be constructed dynamically/incrementally: we can use `GetByteArrayElements` to gain access to the `jbyteArray` contents; then calling `ReleaseByteArrayElements` with zero-valued 3rd arg ensures data is copied back (whether-or-not the underlying memory is pinned).

Comment: Ow... I'm sorry, I don't get it. Thank you very much anyway, it's helped me lot.

Comment: @Roman ~ no problemo. & of course one could do what you're suggesting: gain access to the `rawjBytes` and `memcpy` them into some other memory location. so i appreciate the potential for confusion &&so it's good you pointed it out :)

Comment: In your SetByteArrayRegion() example, I think you're using "jbyteArray" in the args list when you mean to use "result", right? (ie: use the var name, not its type)

Comment: @Trent Gray-Donald +1 ~blinking! imagine failing to notice that before.lol. ~fixed.