# Android ImageView is not being updated

Tags: android, c++, bitmap, android-ndk

I pass the bitmap to android ndk, keep the pixels in my class and according to the user touch I change the pixels with corresponding (jni)c++ calls. But imageview is not being updated. When I write bitmap in file I see that bitmap is changed. Also, when I click on Home button and return back to app, I see the changes. What can be the reason of such strange behavior?
Aslo, this problem exists on Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1(Android 4.0.3) but in galaxy Tab 7.0 works fine.

What I have tried so far:

1. I have tried to invalidate the Imageview - doesn't work.
2. Copy the bitmap and reset Imageview's bitmap - works.
3. Call c++ methods in separate thread - doesn't work.

Comment: Try to force `View` redrawing after bitmap has changed by calling `imageView.invalidate()` from UI thread or `imageView.postInvalidate()` from other threads.

Comment: I tried that, still the save effect.

Answer (score 0):

When you write bitmap file, is it operated in C++ part? If so, java and NDK is not perfectly synchronized. Then, it may helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10384585/1811103