# Invoking java method using jni

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have the following method in java which i try to call from cpp,

```
public void callback(short[] sArray) {
    Log.e("java", ""+sArray.length);
}
```

in cpp i tried this code to invoke the java method:

```
jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
jmethodID mid =
env->GetMethodID(cls, "callback", "([S)V");
    if (mid == NULL) {
        return 0; // method not found
    }
     //short *sbuffer;
     //sbuffer is filled with some data
    env->CallVoidMethod(obj, mid,sbuffer);
```

but i got this error:

> 05-28 18:13:29.850: W/dalvikvm(18423): Invalid indirect reference
>   0x75402008 in decodeIndirectRef 05-28 18:13:29.850: E/dalvikvm(18423):
>   VM aborting 05-28 18:13:29.850: A/libc(18423): Fatal signal 11
>   (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 18423 (ssconverterdemo)

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the method require an array parameter, you can't pass C array to java.

[How to return an array from JNI to Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610045/how-to-return-an-array-from-jni-to-java)

this explain how to pass array from jni to java

Answer (score 0):

Things like `CallVoidMethod` or else accepts parameters in format of `jvalue`. You need to translate your `sbuffer` into jshortArray and then make a jvalue representing it, then pass the `jvalue` entry to `CallVoidMethod`.