# How to return vector<vector<Point>> from JNI to Java?

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android

I'm developing an Android application to find the largest contour from an input image.

I found a working example in c++.

I tried to adapt it to my project and I'm trying to make a JNI function to return th results.

I'm stuck at returning the list of found contours from JNI to Java.

Here is my JNI code which isn't working for now

```
extern "C"
jobjectArray
Java_com_grimg_coffretpfe_Activities_CompareActivity_getQuadrilateral(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject /* this */,
    jlong grayscale,
    jlong output) {

Mat* mGray = (cv::Mat*) grayscale;
Mat* mOutput = (cv::Mat*) output;

Mat convexHull_mask(mGray->rows, mGray->cols, CV_8UC1);
convexHull_mask = Scalar(0);

vector<vector<Point>> contours;
findContours(*mGray, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
vector<int> indices(contours.size());
iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);

sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(), [&contours](int lhs, int rhs) {
    return contours[lhs].size() > contours[rhs].size();
});

/// Find the convex hull object
vector<vector<Point> >hull(1);
convexHull(Mat(contours[indices[0]]), hull[0], false);

vector<Vec4i> lines;
HoughLinesP(convexHull_mask, lines, 1, CV_PI / 200, 50, 50, 10);

if (lines.size() == 4) // we found the 4 sides
{
    vector<Vec3f> params(4);
    for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++)
    {
        params.push_back(calcParams(Point(lines[l][0], lines[l][1]), Point(lines[l][2], lines[l][3])));
    }

    vector<Point> corners;
    for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < params.size(); j++) // j starts at i so we don't have duplicated points
        {
            Point intersec = findIntersection(params[i], params[j]);
            if ((intersec.x > 0) && (intersec.y > 0) && (intersec.x < mGray->cols) && (intersec.y < mGray->rows))
            {
                cout << "corner: " << intersec << endl;
                corners.push_back(intersec);
            }
        }
    }

    if (corners.size() == 4) // we have the 4 final corners
    {
        return(corners);
    }
}

return(vector<Point>());
```

}

The return values are wrong, how can I change this piece of code to return those contours?

Comment: You cannot simply return a C++ object to Java like this. Which data type do you expect these to be in Java?

Comment: I expect a list of MatOfPoint.

Comment: The `jobjectArray` you want to return must be allocated with the JNI `NewObjectArray`API. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610045/how-to-return-an-array-from-jni-to-java as a starting point.