# Convert std:set<int> into jintArray

Tags: c++, jint

I'm provided a `std::set<int>` object that I need to convert/copy into a `jintArray` to return to an Android app.  I tried the code below, but it seems to be crashing my app with only this as a clue:

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x2 in tid 19975

I suspect it's the cast, but I'm not sure the right way to do it.  `theId` is definitely an `int`.  See the code below:

```cpp
std::set<int> speciesSet = someFunctionThatReturnsASet();

speciesIDSet = env->NewIntArray(speciesSet.size());

int count = 0;
for ( std::set<int>::iterator itr=speciesSet.begin(); itr != speciesSet.end(); itr++ ) {
    try {
        int theId = *itr;
        // This is the last line of code that runs.
        env->SetIntArrayRegion(speciesIDSet, count, 1, (jint*)theId);
        count++;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "oops";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't cast an int to a pointer of any kind.  Doesn't it just work without the cast?  Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610045/how-to-return-an-array-from-jni-to-java

Answer (score 1):

`SetIntArrayRegion()` expects an array as the source buffer. You are trying to pass it an "array" of 1 `int` at a time. Which is fine, but as another answer pointed out, you need to use `(jint*)&theId` instead of `(jint*)theId` to do that.

Another option would be to create an actual array first, then call `SetIntArrayRegion()` only 1 time to copy the entire array in one go:

```cpp
std::set<int> speciesSet = someFunctionThatReturnsASet();

std::vector<int> speciesVec(speciesSet.begin(), speciesSet.end());

speciesIDSet = env->NewIntArray(speciesVec.size());
env->SetIntArrayRegion(speciesIDSet, 0, speciesVec.size(), reinterpret_cast<jint*>(speciesVec.data()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you want to write `(jint*)&theId` instead of `(jint*)theId`.

The second one is saying, you want to interpret that number as jint* pointer. But you want jint* pointer to the number.