# Creating and setting an array through JNI

Tags: java, c++

This is my function that, given an object and a field, sets an array into this field with the giveen `array`

```
static void createFillAndSetIntArrayField(JNIEnv *env, jobject *javaInstance, jfieldID* field, int *array, int arrayLength)
    {
        jintArray intJavaArray = env->NewIntArray(arrayLength);
        env->SetIntArrayRegion(intJavaArray, 0, arrayLength, array);
        env->SetObjectField(*javaInstance, *field, intJavaArray);
    }
```

and I'm calling like this

```
JniUtils::createFillAndSetIntArrayField(env, &pixelFormatInstance, &yuvInternalFormat, pixelFormat_->yuvInternalFormat, 3);
```

But in Java I get an array of all 0s

I'm sure that `pixelFormatInstance` exists. What am I possibly doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Following the suggestions:

```
static void createFillAndSetIntArrayField(JNIEnv *env, jobject *javaInstance, jfieldID *field, int *array, int arrayLength)
    {
        jintArray intJavaArray = env->NewIntArray(arrayLength);
        jint fill[arrayLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
        {
            fill[i] = array[i];
        }
        env->SetIntArrayRegion(intJavaArray, 0, arrayLength, fill);
        env->SetObjectField(*javaInstance, *field, intJavaArray);
    }
```

But I'm still getting 0

Comment: You need to populate each item - your code just populates the first item.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610045/how-to-return-an-array-from-jni-to-java

Comment: @cup im still receiving 0, can you see my update?

Comment: fill[arraylength] is a C99 feature that does not exist in C++.  Try changing the file to a C file.  Alternatively if you have to use C++ use new and delete on the fill array.