# How can I share memory between java and rust?

Tags: java, rust, java-native-interface, shared-memory, gpgpu

I am currently working on a GPU-accalerated fractal viewer. Because of a missing easy-to-use GUI library in **Rust-lang** I want to pass the generated **Image(Object)** to **java**. Is it possible to run such an application efficiently? Which interface do I need?

Comment: Why not embed an HTTP server in the rust program and let it serve images via HTTP to whatever you want? An app, a web page, a standalone Java program, or whatever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return an array from JNI to Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610045/how-to-return-an-array-from-jni-to-java)

Comment: You can use JNI or JNA to call a rust library from Java, or you can use JNI to run a JVM from rust code and call Java code.